# Issue with isdigit(); - scanf validator

Tags: c, string, validation

I need to see if a string, in C language, is full with only letters or if there's any number.

**My code:**

```
char Name[50];
int flag = 0;
int charString = 0;

printf("Please insert your name\n");
scanf("%[^ A-Z\n]",Name);

while (Name[charString]){
flag = isdigit(Name[charString]);

    while(flag){
        getchar();
        printf("ERROR! Please insert only letters");
        scanf("%[^ A-Z\n]",I.Nome);
    }
charString++;
}
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. For example, you have a loop `while (flag)`, but `flag` cannot change its value in the loop, so that it will loop forever. Your loops are also nested the wrong way: The outer lop should be the one that ensures that the name is valid. The inner one should check the string. Pro tip: Make the test into a separate function.

Comment: There is no question here, can you kindly tell us what is your issue?

Comment: Do you mean **letters** as only `a-z` characters?

Comment: yes @BLUEPIXY, alphabetic letters only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char Name[50], nl=0;
    int stat;

    printf("Please insert your name\n");
    stat=scanf("%49[a-z]%c", Name, &nl);

    while(stat != 2 || nl != '\n'){
        while(getchar() != '\n');//drop upto newline
        printf("ERROR! Please insert only letters\n");
        stat=scanf("%49[a-z]%c", Name, &nl);
    }
    printf("your name is '%s'\n", Name);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want user user to input digits, disable input of digits.
This will ignore all the keys except alphabets or space and even don't display them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void main()
{
   char name[50];
   char key=0;
   int i=0;
   while(1)
  {
     key=getch();           //get input from keyboard
    if(!key)
      getch();              //if pressed key is a extended ASCII key ignore it

    if(isalpha(key)||key==32)
      putch(name[i++]=key); //if pressed key is a-z or A-Z or space, display it and add to name.
    else if( key==8 && i>=0) //if backspace is pressed erase a character before it
    {
      printf("%c%c%c",8,32,8);
      i--;
    }
    else if(key==13)       //if enter key is pressed end the loop
    break;
  }
  name[i]='\0';//end of the string
}
```

Comment: I like this technique, it just doesn't answer the question, i.e. does not address the issue. But I prefer this technique in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `"[^ A-Z\n]"` is excluding uppercase characters, you can exlude numbers but doing `"[^ A-Z0-9\n]"`.

And then to check if the input is valid just check that `scanf()` returns `1`

```
if (scanf("%[^ A-Z0-9\n]", Name) != 1)
{
    printf("Invalid Input!\n");
    /* do something about it */
}
```